# сортировка списка по гласным Python

Tags: python, сортировка

Ка отсортировать список по количеству гласных.
к примеру есть список
my_list = ['test', 'bob', 'send', 'itemy']

нужно отсортировать значения по количеству гласных

сделал подсчет гласных
потом сделал упаковку двух списков в словарь и сортировку через sorted().
быть может есть способ проще?

Comment: Добавьте код, его проще читать, чем объяснения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В методах сортировки `sort` и `sorted` есть параметр `key` по нему можно указывать критерии, например возвращать количество гласных

Пример:

```
my_list = ['test', 'bob', 'send', 'itemy']
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: sum(c in "aeiou" for c in x))
print(my_list)
# ['test', 'bob', 'send', 'itemy']
```

Comment: можно обойтись без if:`sum(c in "aeiou" for c in x)`

Comment: @Danis, согласен :)